# Magento 2 Add block before another block using XML

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.2, xml

I want to move `minicart` block to `top.links` block.

This did the trick for me:

`<move element="minicart" destination="top.links" />`

Now, I added a custom block with custom `.phtml` file to the top.links block too:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="fw.account" template="Magento_Theme::html/FlavourWarehouseAccountDropdown.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

That works as expected too.

However, I need the block "**fw.account**" to be rendered before the "**minicart**". I tried adding the "before" and "after" to blocks but with no success.

How can I add the `fw.account` block before `minicart` block? Adding `before="minicart"` to `fw.account` block didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below code to move minicart to toplinks :

```
<move element="minicart" destination="top.links" after="fw.account" />
```

Comment: This is correct answer :) thank you! see my answer for explanation to what happen :) upvoted ;)

Comment: If this is the correct answer then please mark it as a correct so that it will help to others!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<move element="minicart" destination="top.links" before="fw.account" />
```

Comment: Actually this solved my problem, however, is not completly the correct answer : see my answer. Upvote from me :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the XML was working correct from the first time. I had a css class on both elements with `float: right` property, so when they were rendered the first element were pushed back after the second element, therefore it looked like it wasn't working properly.

So technically, both answers I received from @SenhaPanchal and @Divya are correct.

Adding the `after="fw.account` is the correct answer to how to place the element.

However, with the `float: right` CSS property on both elements, this had to be switched around so `before="fw.account"` in conjunction with `float: right` actully resulted in the `minicart` rendering **after** the `fw.account` element.